# KMS server in Azure for onsite physical client devices?

Tags: azure, kms

Is it possible to have a Microsoft KMS license server in the Azure cloud, that licenses physical Windows 10 laptops and tablets used by an organization's students/employees?

Apparently this is possible, though each personal device may need an administratively managed VPN client, such as Azure Point to Site VPN, to communicate with the organization's personal cloud KMS server.

I am not finding direct Microsoft documentation for physical device KMS licensing via the Azure cloud service, though perhaps they expect people to figure this out indirectly on their own?

I do see Microsoft documentation for using KMS for Azure server virtual machines and virtual desktops, but that seems to be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run a KMS server in Azure. If you need your on-premises resources to talk to it then they need to have connectivity to this machine. There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Open up the NSG to allow traffic over the internet but only from your corporate IP ranges
2. Setup a VPN between client locations and Azure
3. Implement Azure Express Route